# How to apply Runge Kutta method to this equation

Tags: numerical-methods, finite-element-method, runge-kutta-methods

I'm trying to solve three dimensional heat equation. I use the method of lines to discretize the spatial part,and choose five point stencil. I got the following equation:

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d} U}{\mathrm{d} t}= \alpha\left [ \frac{-U_{i-2,j,k}+16U_{i-1,j,k}-30U_{i,j,k}+16U_{i+1,j,k}-U_{i+2,j,k}}{12(\Delta x)^{2}} +\frac{-U_{i,j-2,k}+16U_{i,j-1,k}-30U_{i,j,k}+16U_{i,j+1,k}-U_{i,j+2,k}}{12(\Delta y)^{2}} +\frac{-U_{i,j,k-2}+16U_{i,j,k-1}-30U_{i,j,k}+16U_{i,j,k+1}-U_{i,j,k+2}}{12(\Delta z)^{2}} \right ] $$

I am trying to apply Runge-kutta method of fourth order. Knowing that this is defined as:

$$y_{n+1}= y_{n}+ \frac{1}{6} (k_{1}+ 2k_{2}+2k_{3}+k_{4})\Delta t$$

Being $k_{1}, k_{2},k_{3}$ and $k_{4}$ equal to:

$$k_{1}=f(t_{n},y_{n}), $$

$$k_{2}=f(t_{n}+ \frac{\Delta t}{2},y_{n}+ \frac{\Delta t}{2}k_{1}), $$

$$k_{3}=f(t_{n}+ \frac{\Delta t}{2},y_{n}+ \frac{\Delta t}{2}k_{2}),$$

$$ k_{4}= f(t_{n}+\Delta t, y_{n}+k_{3}\Delta t)$$

Since I have presented the Runge-kutta method in a general way, I would like to understand how to apply it to the problem that I am trying to solve with the method of lines.

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: You put the grid points in one big vector and make a function that computes the application of the difference operator. You have to solve the question of how to treat the boundary points. After that you can apply RK4 or any other ODE solver. Take care of step size limitations.